# Writing a Main Method to call an Object?

Tags: java

We are learning Java with BlueJ and I am finding BlueJ very unclear and confusing. We've been given an assignment and one of the first steps is 'create a main method to call the `Train` object'. I'm sure he meant 'to call the Train method'.

Anyway, I'm trying to get the main method to call the Train method in the code below so when you pass a string argument in BlueJ, it executes the code in main. That's it. The Train method passes in a String and two int values:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Train train = new Train();
    train.Train();
}
```

I keep getting an error when trying to do this though and not sure why.

This is the code for the Train Class:

```
public class Train
{
    //Fields
    /* Destination of the Train */
    private String destination = new String();

    /* Train number - identifies the Train */
    private int TrainNumber;

    /* Capacity of the Train - how many customers can be in it */
    private int capacity;

    /* Number of customers currently in the Train */
    private int numberInTrain;

    /* Ticket price - how much a ticket costs. */
    private int ticketPrice;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Train train = new Train();
        train.Train();
    }

    /** Constructor for Train
     * @param dest the destination of the Train
     * @param num the number of the Train
     * @param cap the capacity of the Train
     */
    public void Train(String dest, int num, int cap)
    {
        destination = dest;
        capacity = cap;
        TrainNumber = num;

        numberInTrain = 0;
        ticketPrice = 50;
    }

    //mutators
    /* Records customer taking Train */
    public void enterTrain ()
    {
        numberInTrain = numberInTrain + 1;
    }

    /* Records customer leaving Train */
    public void leaveTrain ()
    {
        numberInTrain = numberInTrain - 1;
    }

}
```

This however, gives me an error and I cannot run the program from main. Any hints to the right direction will be appreciated.

The error is:

> Error:(30, 14) java: method Train in class TrainAssignment.Train cannot be applied to given types;
>     required: java.lang.String,int,int
>     found: no arguments
>     reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

EDIT
I have tried

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Train train = new Train();
    train.Train(dest, num, cap);
}
```

and this also gives an error of cannot find variables. **The values need to come from user input**. When an object is created, we input the destination, the number of people and the capacity for each object.

Comment: The `Train#Train()` method expects 3 arguments. You are passing none. Also, I suggest you read up on [class and method naming conventions](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/java-naming-conventions/). `Train` as a method name in the `Train` class is not a good idea

Comment: Your method (which has a terrible name by the way) is `Train(String dest, int num, int cap)` and you are trying to call it like `train.Train();` - where are `dest`, `num` and `cap` in your call?

Comment: @Phil the arguments are from userinput though from (String dest, int nm, int cap)?

Comment: See where you have `train.Train()`? That's zero arguments. You need to pass in a string and two integers, eg `train.Train("a", 1, 2)`

Comment: @Sam: The only time vanilla Java will populate a method's arguments with user input is when running the main method (the `args` parameter in your example).  Any other time you as the programmer are responsible for providing the parameters to the method.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I tried this and I get an error stating cannot find variable (also the train Method is the method name given by our teacher)

Comment: Omitting `dest`, `num` and `cap` is not going to work when your method requires them.

Comment: Your _"constructor"_ (as indicated in code comments) is not a constructor since they do not have return types. For it to be a constructor, it should be `public Train(String dest, int num, int cap)`. To use it, you would pass in those 3 arguments when creating an instance, eg `Train train = new Train("destination", 1, 2);` You would then be able to call either `train.enterTrain()` or `train.leaveTrain()`. Those are the only methods available

Comment: _"`train.Train(dest, num, cap);`"_  those three variables are not defined. Where do you expect them to come from?

Comment: @Phil they are defined in Train(String dest, int num, int cap)?

Comment: @Sam When you call `train.Train(dest, num, cap);`, you are essentially saying, "Here are these variables, create a Train object using them". However, you never define what those variables' values actually are. To fix it, you would need to define the "dest", "num", and "cap" _before_ you call `train.Train(dest,num,cap);`

Comment: Please don't make more work for others by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange (SE) network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0), for SE to distribute the content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By SE policy, the non-vandalized version is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. Please see: [How does deleting work? …](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221). If permitted to delete, there's a "delete" button below the post, on the left, but it's only in browsers, not the mobile app.

Answer (score 3):

Your professor has it correct. You want to call the Train object. When you call `Train train = new Train();` That is instantiating a Train object, and will call the constructor of the class.

Essentially, that is what you are trying to do here:

```
public void Train(String dest, int num, int cap)
```

This here, however, does not count as a constructor. The constructor has no return type, and as such it can't even be void. So it would be as such:

```
 public Train(String dest, int num, int cap)
```

With doing that, you can remove the `train.Train();` and just have the `Train train = new Train();`. But there is one more issue regarding that. When you call the Train object, the constructor will be expecting 3 parameters, your String and two Ints. So when you call the object, you must fill it with the parameters that you want, such as `Train train = new Train("Canada",2,3);`

EDIT:

I see you now need the parameters to come from user input. I suggest looking up the Scanner class to find out how to get user input.